# TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found bse64 from image

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this case, i want to convert an image to string using base64. then i convert to integer using ord() method. But i got an error. this is my simple code:

```
def input_image_to_string():
filename = filedialog.askopenfile(
    initialdir="/",
    title="Pilih Gambar",
    filetypes=(
        ("png files", "*.png"),
        ("jpg files", "*.jpg"),
        ("bmp files", "*.bmp")
    )
)
image = filename.name
with open(image, 'rb') as file:
    result = base64.b64encode(file.read())
return result

def Hash_the_image(string, panjang):
    input = [ord(character) for character in string]
    print("Convert to Integers: \n" , input)
    pesan_block = array_t(uint8_t, panjang)
    masukan = pesan_block([uint8(i) for i in input])
    hasil = gimli_hash(masukan, panjang)
    print("Hasil hashing: ")
    return hasil
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = input_image_to_string()
    panjang = len(input)
    print(panjang)
    output = Hash_the_image(input, panjang)
    print(output)
```

this is my error:

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode returns *bytes*. You might also want to avoid names like *input*, *string*. 2nd function argument should not be present, you could get the length inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing Bytes always return integers in Python3 (already representing the Unicode code point):

```
>>> x = b'abc'
>>> x[1]
98
>>> ord('b')
98
```

`ord()` is obsolete:

```
...
def Hash_the_image(input, panjang):
    input = [character for character in input]  # keep ints ...
    print("Convert to Integers: \n", input)
    pesan_block = array_t(uint8_t, panjang)
    masukan = pesan_block([uint8(i) for i in input])
    hasil = gimli_hash(masukan, panjang)
    print("Hasil hashing: ")
    return hasil
...
```

Out:

```
31796
Convert to Integers:
[105, 86, ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the Code Below:

```
def input_image_to_string():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(
        initialdir="/",
        title="Pilih Gambar",
        filetypes=(
            ("png files", "*.png"),
            ("jpg files", "*.jpg"),
            ("bmp files", "*.bmp")
        )
    )
    image = filename.name
    with open(image, 'rb') as file:
        result = base64.b64encode(file.read())
    return result

def Hash_the_image(string, panjang):
    input = [ord(str(character)) for character in string]
    print("Convert to Integers: \n" , input)
    pesan_block = array_t(uint8_t, panjang)
    masukan = pesan_block([uint8(i) for i in input])
    hasil = gimli_hash(masukan, panjang)
    print("Hasil hashing: ")
    return hasil
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = input_image_to_string()
    panjang = len(input)
    print(panjang)
    output = Hash_the_image(input, panjang)
    print(output)
```

Comment: `str(character)` will almost surely give the wrong results. That will turn the ord of the character into a string, which will likely cause `ord` to raise an error.

Comment: i still got error, TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found

Comment: can the ord() function convert a string of symbols? or maybe no?