# ord() expected string, but int found

Tags: python

I'm having problem in the `ord()` def, my code is given below:

```
def write(data):
    for block_idx in list(range(0, len(data), 10)):
        chksum = 0
        for byte_idx in list(range(block_idx, 2)):
            chksum += ord(data[byte_idx])


write(b'123')
```

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found bse64 from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637028/typeerror-ord-expected-string-of-length-1-but-int-found-bse64-from-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing `b'123'` to the function, which is bytes, that is why when you're trying to get the byte of an specific position you're getting an int. And when you're passing an `int` to the `ord()`, the exception is thrown, because:

> Given string of length 1, the ord() function returns
> an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when
> the argument is a Unicode object, or the value of the byte when the
> argument is an 8-bit string.

Use:

```
chksum += ord(chr(data[byte_idx]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Python [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) documentation states:

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text,
> bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers

When `b"123"[0]` is called it returns an `int` which is an invalid argument to the builtin [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord) function.

You don't even need to call ord in this case:

```
chksum += data[byte_idx]
```